# Transform unicode character in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm working with MySql. And I want to transform some unicode characters to English characters like that :
á  => a, ứ => u, ư => u , ... 
Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was possible to do using collation transformation, but got only '?' characters.

In this case, I'd suggest you to replace all those characters, and some other -

```
SELECT
  'áứư', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('áứư', 'á', 'a'), 'ứ', 'u'), 'ư', 'u')
```